# ETH mining using Antminer S9 13 TH/s

Tags: ether, mining, mining-pools, solo-mining

I am planning to buy Antminer S9 13 for ETH mining. This mining machine produces the hash rate of 13 TH/s. Which is incredible.
Some questions are raising in my mind.

**1)** According to cost and profit calculators on the web, the income is going to be ridiculously high even if keeping power cost double.

For instance, on this website minergate.com it is giving profit per day $970402.48. Even if keeping electricity cost triple.

How be the real calculation calculated?

**2)** Other than difficulty level, on which factor the earning depends?

Any kind of information is highly appreciated.

Comment: You [cannot use an Antminer for mining ether](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4qt0ad/can_i_use_a_antminer_for_ether/), they only work for Bitcoin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Antminer S9 13 is an ASIC-based Bitcoin miner - it won't work for Ethereum, I'm afraid.

Ethereum uses a different hashing algorithm to Bitcoin, partly to ensure that ASIC-based hardware can't be used to mine ETH.

See:

- [Is Ethereum ASIC resistant?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16811/is-ethereum-asic-resistant)
- [By what mechanism are ASIC-based miners made less favourable?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/33/by-what-mechanism-are-asic-based-miners-made-less-favourable)
- [Ethash Design Rationale](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethash-Design-Rationale)

Comment: Write in detail? why type of miner I need? What is ASIC-based? What is Etherium XXX-based?

Comment: Hi there. If you are new to mining, you will need to learn the basics before thinking about buying mining hardware. This site perhaps isn't the best place to learn the main ideas - somewhere like Reddit might be better because it allows for proper discussions. https://www.reddit.com/r/EtherMining/. A few things to think about are solo mining vs. pool mining (solo mining is no longer profitable), and the fact that Ethereum will move to Proof-of-Stake in the future, so there will be no mining.

Comment: That is f**** cool idea